# Order of actions in combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, spells, attack, move-action

Is there a specific order in which move / move-equivalent actions and standard actions should occur during a combat round?  I know you can take the 5-foot step at the beginning or the end of the turn, but I'm confused about whether or not the move and standard actions are interchangeable.

Thanks for your help!

--Tyr

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the rules make no mention of any requirement to perform actions of certain types before actions of certain other types. You have a set number of actions of various types (some of which can be exchanged for others), but you can take them in any order.